# Uniqueness of Solution for cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm working on characteristics for partial differential equations and the example given is the equation $yu_x-xu_y=0$ with the condition $u|_{x=1}=y^2$. I could come up with one solution on the spot, but the book I'm using says the solution is not unique. So far I couldn't come up with another solution than $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$. I understand that the methods of characteristics results in all soultions to be functions of $x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, the characteristics are concentric circles centred at the origin. The difficulty is that any such circle of radius $r < 1$ fails to intersect the line $x = 1$. Therefore, the condition $u|_{x = 1} = y$ tells us nothing about the values of $u$ on circles of radius $r < 1$!

So I claim that $u(x,y) = g(r)$ is a solution, where $g(r)$ is *any* function of $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ chosen so that $u(x,y)$ is differentiable, and so that $g(r) = r^2 - 1$ for $r \geq 1$. (But there is no constraint on $g(r)$ when $r < 1$, other than the differentiability condition.)

For example, we could take $g(r) = r^2 -  1$ for all $r$. This is your example.

But we could also take:
$$ g(r) = \begin{cases} r^2 - 1 + r^2 (1 - r)^2 & \ \  r < 1 \\ r^2 - 1 & \ \ r \geq 1.\end{cases}$$
Unless I made a mistake (which is quite possible, so please check!), this choice of $g(r)$ also makes $f(x,y)$ differentiable everywhere, and it solves the PDE with $u|_{x = 1} = y$.

Comment: In case $r<1$ your solution $u(1,y)=(1+y^2)-1+(1+y^2)\left(1-\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)^2\neq y^2$ doesn't satisfy the specified condition $u(1,y)=y^2$.

Comment: @JJacquelin If $r < 1$, then the circle of radius $r$ does not intersect the line $x = 1$. Therefore, there DOES NOT EXIST a point that has both $r < 1$ and $x = 1$. So the condition $u(1,y) = y^2$ simply DOES NOT APPLY on a circle of radius $r < 1$.

Comment: Why repeating again and again that  there does not exist a point that has both $r<1$  and $x=1$ ? That is an obvious fact. The condition $u(1,y)=y^2$   does not apply on a circle of radius $r<1$ Without this condition it is also an obvious fact that they are an infinity of solutions. For each of those solutions the condition $u(1,y)=y^2$ is not satisfied since the condition doesn't apply. However, this condition should be satisfied as it is clearly specified in the wording of the question. So all those solutions (which are solutions of the PDE) are not solution of the problem.

Comment: @JJacquelin No, the fact that there does not exist a point with both $r < 1$ and $x = 1$ means that the condition that $u(x,y) = y^2$ when $x =1 $ IS satisfied on these circles. The condition is satisfied vacuously. It's just like how the statement that "all purple rabbits eat fish" is a true statement because there are no purple rabbits.

Comment: Well, if we go into the questions of semantic of the terms used in the wording of the question, I withdraw from the discussion. Since the OP accept your answer, all's well that ends well. Best regards.

Comment: @JJacquelin I suppose this is ultimately an issue about how we understand the question! Thank you for the discussion anyway - I enjoyed thinking about this problem! By the way, I really like the way you obtained the characteristics in your answer (+1). :)

Answer (score 1):

$$yu_x-xu_y=0$$
From the characteristic set of ODEs $\quad \frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{du}{0}\quad$ the equations of two characteristic curves can be derived :

$u=c_1$ and$\quad xdx+ydy=0\quad\to\quad x^2+y^2=c_2\quad$ which leads to the general solution of the PDE :
$$u(x,y)=F(x^2+y^2)$$
At this point they are an infinity of solutions. The question is is there only one solution if the specified condition $u(1,y)=y^2$ is added ?

$u(1,y)=F(1+y^2)=y^2$

Let $X=1+y^2 \quad\to\quad y^2=X-1=F(X)$

So, the function $F(X)=X-1$ is determined. This is a one to one relationship. For each value of X only one value of $F(X)$ exists.

Putting this function $F(X)$ where $X=x^2+y^2$ into the above general solution gives only one particular solution of the PDE :
$$u(x,y)=X-1=(x^2+y^2)-1$$
The specified solution is sufficient to reduce the number of solutions to one solution only.

Comment: Dear @JJacquelin, what if $x^2 + y^2 = c_2$ with $c_2 < 1$? My idea was that the condition $u(1,y) = y^2$ tells us nothing in this case, since there is no point on the circle $x^2 +y^2 = c_2$ with $x = 1$ if $c_2 < 1$.

Comment: A given specified condition has to be satisfied. If a proposed solution doesn't satisfies the condition, this not an acceptable solution. In case of $c_2<1$ we have $u(1,y)\neq y^2$ hence the condition isn't fulfilled and there is no more solution.

Comment: If $c_2 < 1$, then there is no point of the form $(1,y)$ on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = c_2$. So the condition $u(1,y) = y^2$ holds vacuously on circles with $c_2 < 1$. Said another way, the condition $u(1,y) = y^2$ only constrains the value of $u$ on circles with radius $c_2 $ greater than or equal to $1$.